# action script 3 class & mxml file

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder, mxml

I have an AS3 class with some `getVideo` function. I want to use this function in mxml. So I am creating object there and trying to call the function, but I get this error:

> Call to a possibly undefined method.

How can I use my functions in mxml?

My AS3 :

```
public class InitVideoSound 
    {
        var video:Video = new Video();

        public function InitVideoSound()
        {...}

        public function getVideo():Video {
            return video;
        }
```

My mxml :

```
<fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[           

            var ivs1 : InitVideoSound;

            public function init(){
            ivs1.getVideo();

            start.enabled = false;
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
```

Comment: Everything looks correct. Are you sure that is the line that causes the error?

Comment: Why is `start.enabled = false;` in your code snippet? Your code snippets are difficult to debug, as you provide little more than headers, and then a random extra line that seems irrelevant. Try revising them, or provide more information.

Comment: It doesn't matter. The question is why IDE says that there is no such function in my class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[           

            var ivs1 : InitVideoSound = new InitVideoSound() ;

            public function init(){
            ivs1.getVideo();

            start.enabled = false;
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
```

Make sure the neccesary import for classes are done.

Comment: This solution would fix a problem with a null reference, but it doesn't sound like that's OP's problem. I could easily be wrong, though.

Comment: i think it was in this line : var ivs1 : InitVideoSound; I changed it to var ivs1 : InitVideoSound = new InitVideoSound() ; and finally i can use my function.

Comment: @user1284054 yes it just created an object to InitVideoSound. So later on when it was referenced, the function getVideo() worked properly.